# Div has gone missing

Tags: html, css

Hey everyone im not sure if its due to positioning or something but my one div .footerwrap has just dissipated from my page it only reappears if i make the positioning relative. Ive managed to get all my other pages working without adding positioning to it and it goes to the bottom nicely. Just my index page is giving me hassles. Anyone have any idea on where it has gone or how to fix?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">   
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Home</title>
        <!--===================================================css links===================================================!-->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600,500,400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,900,100,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="css/default_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/home_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>    
    <body>
        <!--===================================================Header===================================================!-->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="social">
                <aside class="socialfade">  
                    <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/deviant.png"></a>
                    <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/yt.png"/></a>
                    <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/fb.png"/></a>
                </aside><!--close socialfade!-->
            </div>
            <!--close social!-->
            <div class="header">           
                <div class="logo">
                    <aside class="logofade">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" />
                    </aside><!--close logofade-->
                </div>
                <!--close logo-->
            </div>
            <!--close header!-->
            <div class="menu">
                <ul class="menutxt">
                <aside class="menufade">
                        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
                        </li>
                    </aside>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--close menu!-->
            <!--===================================================Fader===================================================!-->
            <div class="fadewrapper">
                <div class="fader">
                    <img class="bottom" src="images/dsas.png" />
                    <img class="top" src="images/dsa.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--===================================================Content===================================================!-->
            <div class="contentwrap">
                <div class="textwrap">
                    <aside class="movefade">
                        <div class="contentspace"></div>
                        <!--close contentspace!-->
                        <div class="content">
                            <p class="headertxt">Specializations</p>
                            <p>With various skills in branding, 
                            multi-media and advertising I am able to provide fresh and inspiring solutions for the task given to me. Using various programs suchas:</p>
                            <p>
                                <img src="images/1436419348_Photoshop.png" />
                                <img src="images/1436419350_Illustrator.png" />
                                <img src="images/1436419354_Dreamweaver.png" />
                                <img src="images/1436419357_Premiere_Pro.png" />
                                <img src="images/1436419359_After_Effects.png" />
                                <img src="images/1436419356_Flash_Pro.png" />
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <!--close content!-->
                        <div class="divider">
                            <img src="images/divide.png" />
                        </div>
                        <!--close divider!-->
                        <div class="content2">
                            <p class="headertxt">Why me?</p>
                            <p>The work I create is reflecting something fresh and exciting in order to meet the clients needs. About pushing for new and innovative ideas and pushing for an end result of brand and product growth</p>
                        </div>
                        <!--close content2!-->
                        <div class="contentspace"></div>
                        <!--close contentspace!-->
                    </aside>
                    <!--close test!-->
                </div>
                <!--close textwrap!-->
            </div>
            <!--close contentwrap!-->
            <!--===================================================Footer===================================================!-->
            <div class="footerwrap">
                <p class="foottxt">Designed and developed by Luke Babich- All Rights Reserved ©2015</p>
            </div>
            <!--close footerwrap!-->
        </div>
        <!--close wrapper!-->
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/*---------------------------- Body and Default ----------------------------*/
body {
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#171717;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color:#CCC;
} 
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
a{
    color:#000;
    transition:300ms;
}
a:hover {
    color:#000;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*---------------------------- Main Wrapper ----------------------------*/
.wrapper{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
/*---------------------------- Header ----------------------------*/
.header{
    position:relative;
    min-height:180px;
    padding-right:225px;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px #333 ;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px #333 ;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px #000;
    z-index:200;
}
.logo{
    position: absolute;
    min-width:60px; 
    top:4%;
}
.logo img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:100%;
}
.social{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    min-width:20px; 
    top:15px;
    right:1%;
    z-index:500;    
}
.social img{
    float:right;
    width:35px;
    display: block;
    padding:0 0 0px 15px;
}
img.move {
    bottom:0px;
    transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.44, 1.2);
}
img.move:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.4, 1.4, 1.4);    
}
/*---------------------------- Menu ----------------------------*/
.menu{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:200px;
    z-index:401;
}
ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li{
    display: inline;
    list-style:none;
    padding:1%;
    transition: all 300ms;
}
li a{
    color:#CCC;
    transition:300ms;
}
li a:hover {
    color:#900;
}
.menutxt{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size:1.8vw;
    font-weight:400;
    z-index:300;
}
/*---------------------------- Footer Text ----------------------------*/
.foottxt{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    background:#070707;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding:15px 0;
    font-size:0.7em;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:200;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*---------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------- FADERS ---------------------------- ----------------------------*/
/*---------------------------- Logo Fader ----------------------------*/
.logofade{
  animation: logofadein 3s;
  -moz-animation: logofadein 3s; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: logofadein 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: logofadein 3s; /* Opera */
}
}
@keyframes logofadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes logofadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes logofadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes logofadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
/*---------------------------- menu Fader ----------------------------*/
.menufade{
    opacity:0;  
    animation: menufadein forwards 3s 1s;;
    -moz-animation:  menufadein forwards 3s 1s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:  menufadein forwards 3s 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation:  menufadein forwards 3s 1s; /* Opera */
}
}
@keyframes  menufadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes  menufadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes  menufadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes  menufadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
/*---------------------------- social Fader ----------------------------*/
.socialfade{
    opacity:0;  
    animation: socialfadein forwards 3s 0.5s;;
    -moz-animation:  socialfadein forwards 3s 0.5s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:  socialfadein forwards 3s 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation:  socialfadein forwards 3s 0.5s; /* Opera */
}
}
@keyframes  socialfadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes  socialfadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes  socialfadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes  socialfadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@charset "utf-8";
/*---------------------------- Image Fader ----------------------------*/
.fader img {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    max-height:550px;
    min-height:200px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    z-index:1;  
}
@keyframes faderFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    45% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    55% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
.fader img.top {
    animation-name: faderFadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
/*---------------------------- Content ----------------------------*/
.contentwrap{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:480px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:300;
    background:#171717;
}
.textwrap{
    width:100%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px 0px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 10px 0px #000;
    z-index:100;
}
/* clearfix */
.textwrap:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.content,
.divider,
.content2,
.contentspace {
    text-align:center;
    float: left;
}
.divider{
    width: 24%;
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
}
.divider img{
    display: block;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.content,
.content2 {
    width: 15%;
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
}
.content img{
    width:15%;
}
.contentspace{
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;   
}
.headertxt{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:2em;
}
/* clearfix */
.contentspace:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
/*---------------------------- Footer ----------------------------*/
.footerwrap{
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:1000;
}
/*---------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------- FADERS ---------------------------- ----------------------------*/
/*---------------------------- Content Fader ----------------------------*/
.movefade{
  opacity:0;  
  animation: fadein forwards 3s 1.5s;
  -moz-animation: fadein forwards 3s 1.5s; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein forwards 3s 1.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: fadein forwards 3s 1.5s; /* Opera */

}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        transform: translate(0,-10px);
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        transform: translate(0,-10px);
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        transform: translate(0,-10px);
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        transform: translate(0,-10px);
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

In the fiddle I made. It would seem that you can see the footer. So it is obviously been hiding behind an image that I have on my side. However as you can see it is still not positioned correctly. So im trying to figure out why `.footerwrap` is not going to the bottom like it should be. http://jsfiddle.net/80ftLxtc/1/

Comment: posting your entire code doesn't help. There are issues with your css. Putting `bottom: 0` doesn't do much when the element's `position` isn't either `absolute fixed or relative`

Comment: Use your browser’s developer tools to investigate the issue.

Comment: If you use positioning like top, bottom, left, right you MUST use postion style. E.g. relative or absolute

Comment: Make the parent of the div's position relative, then make your footer wrap absolute.

Comment: maybe because you missing `position:absolute/fixed` in `footerwrap` and `left:0`... increase `z-index` and so on... well, until I type this answer on mobile You already got few same suggestions by above users :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the CSS in your fiddle. Now footer will always come at the bottom. Check this link here. Let me know if it helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/80ftLxtc/3/

Some Specific CSS changes were

```
.wrapper{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.footerwrap{
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:1000;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Other than changes above, also made a small change in one of div containers which was absolute positioned. Had to change that to relative.

Comment: cool that fix seemed to work in pushing the .footerwrap down to the bottom. Only problem is by changing that absolute to a relative. It put the content in that to the top of the page. I updated the fiddle as i made some modifications to divs that werent needed but basically .textwrap needs to end up just above the footer and i think the .fader img is making messing it

Comment: @factordog: Have updated your fiddle with just the above changes in  ".wrapper" and ".footerwrap"  http://jsfiddle.net/80ftLxtc/7/  Now it works fine.

Comment: .textwrap is still floating at the top. So ill have to play around a bit with it, but you fixed the problem I posted. Thanks :)